# MultiSelect Dropdown in Vue Formulate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-formulate

Is there a way to select multiple options in a dropdown in Vue Formulate? I came accross this code on github, it lets me select multiple options but I don't know how to turn it into a dropdown(a select in Vue Formulate).

This is the code I came accross.

```
<FormulateInput
name="example"
type="select"
:options="{first: 'First', second: 'Second'}"
label="Reproduction template!"
help="Click 'Use This Template' and reproduce your issue!"
multiple
size=1
/>
```

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aja9w.png)

[Want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCl5q.png)

Answer (score 4):

One of the core maintainers of Vue Formulate here. Vue Formulate aspires to work as a standard API for all of the native HTML input types. The 2nd screenshot in your question is not a native input. We would call that a "synthetic" input where there's a bunch of non-native functionality represented in the UI.

You *can* do something like this with Vue Formulate but it would require a custom input type to be registered as a [plugin](https://vueformulate.com/guide/plugins/). This is not something that would be included in the core Vue Formulate library.

Comment: This is a shame.